# Problemas con Boostrap datepicker

Tags: bootstrap, datepicker

Estoy usando `BOOTSTRAP`, para tener un calendario en mi web. Funciona bien, salvo porque al cargar la página, me aparece el calendario ya desplegado.

la definición `HTML` del campo es:

```
<label for="txtfechainicio" class="aligncenter">
     Fecha de Inicio
     <input type='text' id='txtfechainicio' class="datetimepicker" name="txtfechainicio" />
</label>
```

La definición del campo en el `JS`

```
$(function() {
    $('#txtfechainicio').datepicker({maxDate: '+2Y',minDate:'-0Y', autoclose: true});
});
```

He probado dando el foco a algún otro elemento del formulario e incluso usando la opción ´hiden´

```
$('#txtfechainicio').datepicker("hiden");
```

La idea es poder ocultarlo, hasta que el usuario no de el foco al campo de texto. Alguna idea?

Esta es la página cuando carga con la consola
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver, el `textarea`, esta con el foco y el calendario desplegado

Comment: ¿Has comprobado en la consola que no te esté dando ningún error? Con tu código a mí me funciona bien (sólo se muestra al poner el foco en el input) http://jsfiddle.net/ymp5D/427/

Comment: Si he mirado la consola y no me muestra errores

Comment: ¿Puedes poner un pantallazo de cómo te aparece? Es muy raro, la verdad

Comment: mmm, habría que saber por qué tiene el foco ahí pero bueno, haciendo $('#txtfechainicio').datepicker("hide"); te lo ocultará

Comment: Versiones de jQuery y Bootstrap? Realice un plunker con tu código y funciona perfecto =/

Comment: Jquery 1.9 Bootstrap 2.2